# Plot image in the xy-plane and points from cell array above on z-axis: MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, plot, graph

I have

1. An image, saved as an array of pixels.
2. A cell array with the same number of cells as the number of pixels in the image.

Basically, each cell of the cell array corresponds to the position of a pixel in the image.

I want to plot the image in the xy-plane of a 3d plot, and then plot the values in the cell array in the z-plane. The values in each cell correspond to the pixel position of the image and the corresponding z value.

For example,

```
cellarray{1} = [10    2056]
cellarray{2} = [18    1928]
```

With the image displayed in the xy-plane, I'd then want

- A point plotted above pixel 1 of the image, with a z-value of 2056.
- A point plotted above pixel 18 of the image, with a z-value of 1928.

I know I can use `imagesc(image)` to plot the image, but I'm not sure how to convert the date in the cell array to create a 3D plot, with the z values above the corresponding pixels of the image.

Comment: Are the first elements in cellarray{n} unique?

Comment: Yes, they're unique. All the first elements of cellarray{1} are 1, all the first elements of cellarray{2} are 2, etc. Thanks for your help!

Comment: But you state above that, for example, `cellarray{2} = [18 1928]` so the first element is 18, not 2?

Comment: Sorry - I didn't quite get the question the first time around. I meant that all the first elements of cellarray{n} are the same, but they are not necessarily all n. So all the first elements of cellarray{2} are 18, all the first elements of cellarray{3} are 39, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have some cell array, `cellarray`, which contains 16 `[pixel number, z value]` pairs. These two lines set up a random demo...

```
% Set up random cell array, with 1x2 arrays in each cell
% First number in each array is unique pixel number, second is z value
z = num2cell(randi(64,4,4));
cellarray = cell(4,4); for ii = 1:16; cellarray{ii} = [ii z{ii}]; end;
```

Now we want to plot this, so convert it into a 16x2 matrix, where each row is one of the 1x2 cells:

```
% Use the colon (:) to make cell array one column, use cell2mat to convert to matrix
g = cell2mat(cellarray(:));
```

To get 2D x and y coordinates from an index, you can use `ind2sub`.

```
[x, y] = ind2sub([4, 4], g(:,1)); % Change [4, 4] to the size of your image
```

Now you can use `plot3` to plot these, holding on if you want to retain a previous plot (like your image):

```
hold on % to retain previous plot, like from imagesc
plot3(x, y, g(:,2), '.'); % Using the dot to specify points not a line
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO, SO MUCH! This was REALLY helpful and awesome. I was wondering which function you think would work best to graph the image itself in the xy-plane of a 3d plot. imagesc() returns a 2d plot, so I've been using this bit of code:

Comment: No problem, glad I could help